# How to hide fields with a condition in RESTful WS?

Tags: java, rest, web-services, get, jax-rs

I have a class called Report that I need to share using RESTful WS.

1. once in full with all its attributes
2. once in only a reduced version

Normally I'd use something like `@XmlTransient` to hide the fields, but this would prevent the full version from working.

Is there any way to set a condition or to kind of pre-filter fields just before the output so that it doesn't affect other uses of the same class?

My Report class looks like this:

```
public class Report {
    private String reportId;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private Date created;
    private Date modified;
...
}
```

The RESTful sharing for the full Report looks like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/{reportId}")
public Report getReport(@PathParam("reportId") String reportId) {
    return Mock.getReport(reportId);
}
```

The full output I need looks like this:

```
{
   "reportId": "d83badf3",
   "title": "The tales of lamaru",
   "content": "When once the great Imgur started his journey...",
   "created": 1519672434866,
   "modified": 1519672434866
}
```

The short output I need should look like this:

```
{
   "reportId": "d83badf3",
   "title": "The tales of lamaru"
}
```

What is necessary to achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [Jackson view support](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation)

Comment: http://graphql.org/learn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use **Inheritance**?

> Parent

```
public class Report {
    private String reportId;
    private String title;
}
```

> Child

```
public class FullReport extends Report{
    private String content;
    private Date createdp;
    private Date modified;
}
```

When you need full report set return type as `FullReport` otherwise `Report`

Answer (score 1):

Jackson has two different annotations to use when you want to exclude some class members from the JSON serialization and deserialization processes. These two annotations are @JsonIgnore and @JsonIgnoreProperties. 
@JsonIgnoreProperties is an annotation at the class level and it expects that the properties to be excluded would be explicitly indicated in the form of a list of strings.
@JsonIgnore instead is a member-level or method-level annotation, which expects that the properties to be excluded are marked one by one.

try this.

```
public class Report {
    private String reportId;
    private String title;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String content;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date created;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date modified;
...
}
```

Comment: Yes, `@XmlTransient` has the same effect as `@JsonIgnore` in this case. Though I need (1) a full Report JSON and (2) a reduced Report JSON. If I add `@JsonIgnore` in the Report class, I reach the goal of (2), but not the goal of (1).